# Inflate a view inside inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I'm using 3rd party which extends base adapter. In base adapter I have inflated my custom layout and I want another layout to be inflated inside that custom layout.

The 3rd party view is swipable cards and I'm trying to display facebook native ads between the cards

Here is my code

custom_ads_cards.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
 card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
 card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

   <com.facebook.ads.NativeAdLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_advertisement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black_25"
    android:fontFamily="@font/mr"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/advertisement"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The Ad view which I want to disply custom_ad_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_ads_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.facebook.ads.MediaView
    android:id="@+id/card_ad_media"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.facebook.ads.AdIconView
            android:id="@+id/native_ad_icon"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_sponsored_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black_25"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_choices_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/native_ad_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="2"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_50"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/native_ad_social_context"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/native_ad_call_to_action"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black_25"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/native_ad_call_to_action"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#4286F4"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the get view method of my base adapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = view;

v = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_ads_cards, null);
            NativeAdLayout fbAdLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.card_ad_layout);

            com.facebook.ads.NativeAd nativeAd = new com.facebook.ads.NativeAd(myContext, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");

            nativeAd.setAdListener(new NativeAdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMediaDownloaded(Ad ad) {
                    // Native ad finished downloading all assets
                    Log.e("TAG", "CARD ad finished downloading all assets.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                    // Native ad failed to load
                    Log.e("TAG", "CARD ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                    // Native ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                    Log.d("TAG", "CARD ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
                    if (nativeAd != ad) {
                        return;
                    }

                    RelativeLayout fbAdView = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(myContext).
                            inflate(R.layout.custom_ad_layout, fbAdLayout,false);
                    fbAdLayout.addView(fbAdView);

                    LinearLayout adChoicesContainer = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
                    AdOptionsView adOptionsView = new AdOptionsView(myContext, nativeAd, fbAdLayout);
                    adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews();
                    adChoicesContainer.addView(adOptionsView, 0);

                    // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
                    AdIconView nativeAdIcon = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
                    TextView nativeAdTitle = fbAView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
                    MediaView nativeAdMedia = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.card_ad_media);
                    TextView nativeAdSocialContext = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
                    TextView nativeAdBody = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
                    TextView sponsoredLabel = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_sponsored_label);
                    Button nativeAdCallToAction = fbAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);

                    // Set the Text.
                    nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiserName());
                    nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBodyText());
                    nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                    nativeAdCallToAction.setVisibility(nativeAd.hasCallToAction() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
                    nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                    sponsoredLabel.setText(nativeAd.getSponsoredTranslation());

                    // Create a list of clickable views
                    List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
                    clickableViews.add(nativeAdTitle);
                    clickableViews.add(nativeAdCallToAction);

                    // Register the Title and CTA button to listen for clicks.
                    nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(
                            fbAdView,
                            nativeAdMedia,
                            nativeAdIcon,
                            clickableViews);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                    // Native ad clicked
                    Log.d("TAG", "CARD ad clicked!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                    // Native ad impression
                    Log.d("TAG", "CARD ad impression logged!");
                }
            });

            // Request an ad
            nativeAd.loadAd();
    return v;   
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @RahulKumar I've posted the code

Comment: the scope for `nativeAd` might be the problem. can you do v.setTag(nativeAd) at the end just before returning v and see if that works

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you not seeing your `custom_ad_layout.xml` added as a view inside `NativeAdLayout`?

Comment: @RickSanchez Yes I'm not able to see the custom_ad_layout.xml added as a view inside NativeAdLayout

Comment: Can you try without the card view 3rd party library? and I assume ad is loaded successfully and do refer the Facebook ad sample code [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/tree/master/samples/android/AdsSample)

Comment: @RickSanchez It works fine without the 3rd party but I've to display between the cards according the requirement

Comment: @RahulKumar  v.setTag(nativeAd) didn't work for me

Comment: Does your app crash when the ad is loaded the second time? and can you confirm if you are properly getting the advertiser name, body text and other values? PS: I have worked on Facebook Ad SDK.

Comment: I also tried adding my Ad view within Card View. It works fine for me.

Comment: @RickSanchez in simple cardview it worked for me as well but I was trying to add that layout in base adapter and that layout inflates another layout.